# Android Billing how to use setAccountId or assign payment to custom identifier

Tags: java, android, google-play, google-play-services, android-billing

I would like to **allow my users using my app across multiple devices **. Users have to log into my app through firebase auth.

Problem is that **payments are assigned to account that is signed on the device (google play)**, not with account signed into the app.** From firebase auth I can get an email address of the user of my app - this could be used as some unique identifier.

**Problem visualized:**

[image: Problem visualized]

I noticed that in Billing flow there is **.setAccountId("some id")** I think I could use this to fill in a unique identifier of a user. But how can use it querying purchases?

```
BillingFlowParams.Builder builder = new BillingFlowParams.Builder()
                .setAccountId("some id")
                .setSku(PREMIUM_YEAR_SUBS).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS);
```

**TLDR**: All I want to do is to retrieve purchases that are connected to my **APP** user account, **not** device account **(google play currently logged in user)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To implement billing using `accountId`, try using the [`getBuyIntentExtraParams()`](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html#getBuyIntentExtraParams) method which provides additional functionality as compared with `getBuyIntent()` method.

With this method, you may use `accountId` with the following description:

> Optional obfuscated string that is uniquely associated with the user's account in your app. If you pass this value, Google Play can use it to detect irregular activity, such as many devices making purchases on the same account in a short period of time.

Additionally, you may want to also check the typical purchase flow with the In-app Billing API discussed [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#purchase).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that we can't get the accountId, the accountId just used by google play.
I guess that you use the accountId to instead of the payload, but after my try, I think that it is not successful.
In the Google Billing Library, the develop payload is removed for the same experience between the in-app-purchase and the out-app-purchase. Though we can add payload in the period of consume or acknowledge, but it useless. And the payload should be set on the period of purchase, but google delete it, and will not be add back. [The payload issues](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63381481).

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `AccountId` attached to each `Purchase` using
[`Purchase.getAccountIdentifiers`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/Purchase#getaccountidentifiers)

It'll return `AccountIdentifiers` object that has
`AccountId` & `ProfileId` that were set previously in `BillingFlowParams` when you launched billing flow

After that you can compare the current user account id with the account id attached to each purchase
to detect the purchases that are connected to the current user account